# Removing Automatic Redirects Without Plugin

Tags: plugins, redirect, slug

I've been working on a wordpress site and run into the automatic redirect feature when you change a slug. On the current site I am using the Redirects plugin, and was able to modify the redirects so that I could reuse slugs that had been altered without getting the infinite loop problem.

My company has a similar wordpress site that is not using the Redirects plugin. I am curious to know how I would be able to remove a redirect from a slug that WordPress has put into place without installing Redirects. From my understanding, it's in the database somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 3):

There's a canonical_redirect, or redirect_canonical function, which gets hooked onto template_redirect. Just remove it using remove_action() in your config file or your theme's functions file...